# open editor using a button on another editor RCP, SWT, JAVA

Tags: java, swt, rcp, jface

I have one RCP program, with 3 parts - 2 views(on left, 2 parts) and various editors(on right and the other part). 
On my views i have trees and I can open the editor (other part). 
On editor i can open another editor, but i need past an object when I call the editor, i make it on : `addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {....`

my button:

```
btnNewButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {

                  IHandlerService handlerService = (IHandlerService) getSite().getService(IHandlerService.class);

                  try {
                        handlerService.executeCommand("XPTO.command", null);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(
                                "XPTO");
                    }
                }
            });
```

my command:

```
public class CallEditors extends AbstractHandler {

@Override
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
    System.out.println("calledEditor");

    // Get the view
    IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event);

    IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();

    Editor navEditor = (Editor) page.findEditor(Editor.IDI);
```

}
}

thanks

---

I have the answer:

```
btnNewButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {

                // Get the view
                IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();

                IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();


                    Object obj = btnNewButton.getData();

                    if (obj != null) {


                      xPTO input = new xPTO();
                          try {

                                 page.openEditor(input, xptoEditor.ID, false);  
                                } catch (PartInitException e1) {
                                    throw new RuntimeException(e1);
                                }
                      }
```

}

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: how can i open an editor using a button on another editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `IWorkbenchPage#openEditor(..)`